# Flutter Android App crashes on start when use stripe_payment

Tags: android, flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to use stripe_payment on my Flutter apps. It works fine on IOS simulators, but the app crashed instantly on Android.

I tried to put the stripe_payment package to a new project, and the app crashed on start as well.

The package version I'm using is: `stripe_payment: ^0.0.9`

Does anyone know how to use the package properly? Thanks a lot !

Comment: checkout this two part  youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGBIb5H2_Xg&list=PLgGjX33Qsw-EMsLf8TmsYhKOCx2ALZiKi&index=77 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8IhufSG-40&index=78&list=PLgGjX33Qsw-EMsLf8TmsYhKOCx2ALZiKi

Comment: Check my answer to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56174623/9783262)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your \android\app\src\main\java\com\example\yourProjectName\MainActivity.java
file you should have code similar to the code below:

```
package com.example.yourProjectName;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

//public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

In order it works for version ^0.1.0,
include this into your project's android/gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: this is for android studio may be. How can I resolve this from Visual Studio Code. can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Use latest dependency

```
dependencies:
  stripe_payment: ^0.1.0
```

use indentation properly.

then use below to get the dependency inside your project

```
flutter packages get
```

and import the dependency inside your page where you are using stripe_payment

```
import 'package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart';
```

if imported dependency won't give you any error then you can use stripe_payment without any error

Comment: I got this message when I build the app with stripe_payment 0.1.0
`Execution failed for task ':stripe_payment:compileDebugKotlin'.`
I think I need to update the sdk version right?

Answer (score 0):

Extend your MainActivity with FlutterFragmentActivity.
Problem Solved..

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flutter with Kotlin, then change the MainActivity.kt file's code to this.

android/app/src/main/kotlin/co/popcrn/app/MainActivity.kt

```
package YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```