# Integrating Stripe Payment in Flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe Payment Gateway in Flutter app and i am following below link

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stripe_payment

But unfortunately i am getting error. I am using dependencies:
stripe_payment: ^0.1.0. But i am getting below error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':stripe_payment:compileDebugKotlin'.

  > Compilation error. See log for more details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[image]

Can anyone please help me to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

In your \android\app\src\main\java\com\example\yourProjectName\MainActivity.java
file you should have code similar to the code below:

```
package com.example.yourProjectName;

import android.os.Bundle;
//import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

//public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
public class MainActivity extends FlutterFragmentActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

In order it works for version ^0.1.0,
include this into your project's android/gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: when doing that, I have an error : `error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation of this plugin for Android:

> Please be aware that your main activity must extend from FlutterFragmentActivity.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through below link, in this demo **stripe** and **PayPal** payment gateway are integrated.

https://github.com/android-inheritx/Flutter_Payment_Stipe_Paypal

In stripe, payment can be done in two ways. First with payment intent and second with charges API.

In the above-mentioned link, stripe payment is achieved by charges API.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue after switching to a different branch.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Fixed it for me.